# Bootstrapping CI for a quantile regression in R outside the quantreg framework

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, quantile-regression

I have an object, `model1`, resulting from a quantile regression. In `model1` I have 3 columns and 99 rows with a step of 1 centile like this:

```
> model1
    tau intercept  julian_day
1  0.01  17.25584 -0.02565709
2  0.02  19.11576 -0.04716498
3  0.03  20.92364 -0.07115870
4  0.04  22.74398 -0.09706853
5  0.05  24.54071 -0.12248334
6  0.06  26.19349 -0.14133451
7  0.07  27.83602 -0.15839657
8  0.08  29.64554 -0.18364227
```

I would like to calculate and plot a confidence interval for the values of the intercept and the variable, using a bootstrapping method.

I did not perform the quantile regression using the `quantreg` package, but instead I used this method:

```
#Functions

    minimize.logcosh <- function(par, X, y, tau) {
      diff <- y-(X %*% par)
      check <- (tau-0.5)*diff+(0.5/0.7)*logcosh(0.7*diff)+0.4
      return(sum(check))
    }
    
    smrq <- function(X, y, tau){
      p <- ncol(X)
      op.result <- optim(
        rep(0, p),
        fn = minimize.logcosh,
        method = 'BFGS',
        X = X,
        y = y,
        tau = tau
      )
      beta <- op.result$par
      return(beta)
    }
    
    run_smrq <- function(data, fml, response) {
      x <- model.matrix(fml, data) #modify
      y <- data[[response]]
      #X <- cbind(x, rep(1,nrow(x)))
      X <- x
      
      n <- 99
      betas <- sapply(1:n, function(i) smrq(X, y, tau=i/(n+1)))
        return(betas) 
    }


#Callers

smrq_models <- df %>%
  group_by(lat_grouped) %>%
  group_map(~ run_smrq(data=., fml=julian_day~year_centered, response="julian_day"))
```

Here is what `df` looks like:

```
> dput(head(df, 20))
structure(list(lat = c("59", "59", "55", "59", "59", "63", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "63", "59", "59", "59", "57", "56", "56", "59", 
"63", "63"), long = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), date = c("1951-03-22", 
"1951-04-08", "1952-02-03", "1952-03-08", "1953-02-22", "1953-03-12", 
"1954-01-16", "1954-02-06", "1954-03-14", "1954-03-28", "1954-04-02", 
"1955-01-23", "1955-03-06", "1955-03-13", "1955-04-08", "1955-04-11", 
"1955-04-12", "1956-03-25", "1956-04-01", "1956-04-02"), julian_day = c(81, 
98, 34, 68, 53, 71, 16, 37, 73, 87, 92, 23, 65, 72, 98, 101, 
102, 85, 92, 93), year = c(1951L, 1951L, 1952L, 1952L, 1953L, 
1953L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 
1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1956L, 1956L, 1956L), decade = c("1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959"), time = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), lat_grouped = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2"), year_centered = structure(c(-36, -36, -35, 
-35, -34, -34, -33, -33, -33, -33, -33, -32, -32, -32, -32, -32, 
-32, -31, -31, -31), class = "AsIs")), row.names = 24:43, class = "data.frame")
```

Do you have any tips on how to achieve my goal? I have tried many boot functions found on the internet but have not been able to make something work so far.

Thank you very much for the help, do not hesitate if I missed something, I can update my post!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72339064/edit) with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, I have done the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a function missing in the question's code.

```
logcosh <- function(x) log(cosh(x))
```

As for the problem, write a function to sample the data.frame's rows with replacement, and run the quantile regressions just like in the question. There is no need to save them in an object `smrq_models` because the results are to be immediately returned to caller.

Note that I have removed the constant `n = 99` from function `run_smrq` and it is now an argument.

Then, call the boot function in a loop.

Finally, to have the bootstrapped estimates, the lists returned by the quantile regression code must be first made an array in order for `apply` to compute the mean values. Assign the row names and we're done.

```r
library(tidyverse)

boot_fun <- function(data, n) {
  i <- sample(nrow(data), nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
  df <- data[i, ]
  df %>%
    group_by(lat_grouped) %>%
    group_map(~ run_smrq(data=., fml=julian_day~year_centered, response="julian_day", n=n))
}

set.seed(2022)

n <- 99L
R <- 10L
boot_smrq_models <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  boot_smrq_models[[i]] <- boot_fun(df, n)
}

l <- length(boot_smrq_models[[1]])
smrq_models_all <- vector("list", length = l)
smrq_models_int <- vector("list", length = l)
for(i in seq.int(l)) {
  tmp <- array(dim = c(R, dim(boot_smrq_models[[1]][[i]])))
  for(j in seq.int(R)) {
    tmp[j, , ] <- boot_smrq_models[[j]][[i]]
  }
  smrq_models_all[[i]] <- t(apply(tmp, 2:3, mean))
  smrq_models_int[[i]] <- apply(tmp, 2:3, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
  rownames(smrq_models_all[[i]]) <- sprintf("tau_%03.02f", (1:99)/(99+1))
}

lapply(smrq_models_all, head)
#> [[1]]
#>                [,1]       [,2]
#> tau_0.01 -23.173185 -1.4624225
#> tau_0.02   3.509690 -0.6640458
#> tau_0.03 -13.748280 -1.2172158
#> tau_0.04 -38.373045 -1.9780045
#> tau_0.05  -8.166044 -1.0890235
#> tau_0.06  51.701066  0.6258957
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>               [,1]      [,2]
#> tau_0.01  1.387311 -2.315114
#> tau_0.02 36.060786 -1.311070
#> tau_0.03  9.177731 -2.111396
#> tau_0.04 22.320567 -1.731685
#> tau_0.05 40.143578 -1.212108
#> tau_0.06 19.900275 -1.812859
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok it seems to work, at least I get a similar output as the one you are showing :) I will just need a little bit of more help, because your code is complex to me. 1) where can I chose the number of replicates (100, 1000, etc?) ; 2)  I got the mean value of the bootstrap in the output if I understand properly. How about getting a confidence interval (p = 0.05)? ; 3) last, I would like to plot the confidence interval generated over my quantile regression, is it possible? Many thanks again for your precious help

Comment: @Recology 1) The variable `R` controls the number of replicates. 2) if you want the bootstrapped CI95 intervals, done, the end-points are now in `smrq_models_int`. 3) I don't know how but yes, it's possible to plot the CI's. Your question doesn't include plot code so I cannot tell you how, maybe that would be another question?

Comment: thank you very much it's working well! I will work on the plot and if I do not manage open a new question