# Plot your own generated confidence interval with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, quantile-regression

Following this question [Bootstrapping CI for a quantile regression in R outside the quantreg framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339064/bootstrapping-ci-for-a-quantile-regression-in-r-outside-the-quantreg-framework/72340868#72340868), I would like to plot the confidence interval, obtained with the solution provided, on my quantile regression plot.

Libraries:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Regression functions:

```
logcosh <- function(x) log(cosh(x))

minimize.logcosh <- function(par, X, y, tau) {
  diff <- y-(X %*% par)
  check <- (tau-0.5)*diff+(0.5/0.7)*logcosh(0.7*diff)+0.4
  return(sum(check))
}

smrq <- function(X, y, tau){
  p <- ncol(X)
  op.result <- optim(
    rep(0, p),
    fn = minimize.logcosh,
    method = 'BFGS',
    X = X,
    y = y,
    tau = tau
  )
  beta <- op.result$par
  return(beta)
}

run_smrq <- function(data, fml, response, n=99) {
  x <- model.matrix(fml, data) #modify
  y <- data[[response]]
  #X <- cbind(x, rep(1,nrow(x)))
  X <- x
  
  betas <- sapply(1:n, function(i) smrq(X, y, tau=i/(n+1)))
  return(betas) 
}
```

Sample data:

```
> dput(head(df, 20))
structure(list(lat = c("59", "59", "55", "59", "59", "63", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "63", "59", "59", "59", "57", "56", "56", "59", 
"63", "63"), long = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), date = c("1951-03-22", 
"1951-04-08", "1952-02-03", "1952-03-08", "1953-02-22", "1953-03-12", 
"1954-01-16", "1954-02-06", "1954-03-14", "1954-03-28", "1954-04-02", 
"1955-01-23", "1955-03-06", "1955-03-13", "1955-04-08", "1955-04-11", 
"1955-04-12", "1956-03-25", "1956-04-01", "1956-04-02"), julian_day = c(81, 
98, 34, 68, 53, 71, 16, 37, 73, 87, 92, 23, 65, 72, 98, 101, 
102, 85, 92, 93), year = c(1951L, 1951L, 1952L, 1952L, 1953L, 
1953L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1954L, 1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 
1955L, 1955L, 1955L, 1956L, 1956L, 1956L), decade = c("1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", 
"1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959", "1950-1959"), time = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), lat_grouped = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2"), year_centered = structure(c(-36, -36, -35, 
-35, -34, -34, -33, -33, -33, -33, -33, -32, -32, -32, -32, -32, 
-32, -31, -31, -31), class = "AsIs")), row.names = 24:43, class = "data.frame")
```

How I obtained my regression plot:

```
#Quantile regression

smrq_models <- df %>%
group_by(lat_grouped) %>%
group_map(~ run_smrq(data=., fml=julian_day~year_centered, response="julian_day"), n=99)

#Gives 3 models; I show for the first one

model1 = as.data.frame(t(smrq_models[[1]]))

names(model1)[1] <- 'intercept'
names(model1)[2] <- 'julian_day'
model1 = rownames_to_column(model1, var = "tau")
model1$tau = seq(0.01, 0.99, by = 0.01)

model1 %>% 
  mutate(Quantile=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Quantile,names_to="beta",values_to = "Coefficient") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Quantile,Coefficient,color=beta)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~beta, scales="free_y")
```

How are obtained the confidence intervals:

```
boot_fun <- function(data, n) {
  i <- sample(nrow(data), nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
  df <- data[i, ]
  df %>%
    group_by(lat_grouped) %>%
    group_map(~ run_smrq(data=., fml=julian_day~year_centered, response="julian_day", n=n))
}

set.seed(2022)

n <- 99L
R <- 10L
boot_smrq_models <- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  boot_smrq_models[[i]] <- boot_fun(df, n)
}

l <- length(boot_smrq_models[[1]])
smrq_models_all <- vector("list", length = l)
smrq_models_int <- vector("list", length = l)
for(i in seq.int(l)) {
  tmp <- array(dim = c(R, dim(boot_smrq_models[[1]][[i]])))
  for(j in seq.int(R)) {
    tmp[j, , ] <- boot_smrq_models[[j]][[i]]
  }
  smrq_models_all[[i]] <- t(apply(tmp, 2:3, mean))
  smrq_models_int[[i]] <- apply(tmp, 2:3, quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
  rownames(smrq_models_all[[i]]) <- sprintf("tau_%03.02f", (1:99)/(99+1))
}

CI <- smrq_models_int
CI_mod1 = smrq_models_int[[1]]
```

The output desired would be, if it is doable, to combine both to add the CI_mod1 values to the regression plot to have something like this (random example):

[image]

Thank you very much for the help, if I am missing to give some informations do not hesitate to ask, I will edit my post.

Comment: Please explicitly list all `library()` calls necessary to run the sample code. It's clear you are using dplyr but its less clear where functions like `run_smrq` come from. If you have the data for your CI, you can add it to your plot with a `geom_ribbon` layer.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for helping. I have edited my post with the libraries and the code used to generate the functions that you are asking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this with `geom_ribbon()`, you just need to merge the CI data with the model coefficient data.

```r
CIs_to_plot <- map_dfr(1:dim(CI_mod1)[3], ~as_tibble(CI_mod1[,,.x], rownames = "pctle"), 
                       .id = "Quantile") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "pctle", values_from = c("V1", "V2")) %>% 
  rename("intercept.low" = `V1_2.5%`, "intercept.high" = `V1_97.5%`,
         "julian_day.low" =`V2_2.5%`, "julian_day.high" = `V2_97.5%`) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Quantile, names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c("beta", ".value")) %>% 
  mutate(Quantile = parse_number(Quantile))
  
model_to_plot <- model1 %>% 
  mutate(Quantile=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Quantile,names_to="beta",values_to = "Coefficient")

model_to_plot %>% 
  left_join(CIs_to_plot, by = c("Quantile", "beta")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Quantile,Coefficient)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = low, ymax = high), fill = "grey", alpha = .5) +
  geom_line(aes(color=beta)) +
  facet_wrap(~beta, scales="free_y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Graph as in the question, with a grey confidence band.]